# How to display scrollbar on hover using swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, scroll, scrollbar

When mouse is moved over the scrollview, scroll bars should appear.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrollview/1403460-flashscrollers
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1525114-mousemoved

To make it appear on view appearance:
The following is the code

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    featureScrollView.flashScrollers()
}
```

Comment: The methods you're using are for macOS. Are you developing for iOS or macOS?

Comment: I am developing for MacOS